# Regular expression for finding a substring not surrounded by other characters

Tags: regex

I've got a regular expression `"(?i).*guitar.*"` but how do I make this **only** match if the word is not surrounded by other characters?

So I thought, let's just add `[^a-zA-Z]` to both ends of the regular expression except when I did that, it no longer matches when the word is at the beginning or very end of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\b` to match at word boundaries:

```
.*\bguitar\b.*
```

This will match "I play my guitar every day", but not "I have a subscription to guitarist magazine".

Comment: This doesn't work - oh wait I needed to escape it like `\\b` - my goodness..